# Duas classes numa tela de Cadastro

Tags: django, django-templates

-2

Tô iniciando no Django, e tenho algumas dúvidas:

1° No código abaixo, como vocês podem ver, tem uma classe chamada Aluno que tem relação com a classe Responsável, eu gostaria de numa tela de cadastro mostrassem as form das duas classes para realizar o cadastro, já que é necessário um Responsável para cadastrar aluno. Eu consegui fazer com o código abaixo, mas não sei se tem algum jeito melhor. Segue uma imagem de como eu quero, e consegui(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzcnj.jpg). Mas minha dúvida é, Tem algum modo melhor de realizar essa tarefa?

2º Eu queria também, pegar a altura e o peso do aluno, para realizar o IMC dele. Como eu faço isso? Quando eu faço a função que pega a altura e o peso, e comparo com EX: 18.5, diz que não é possível comparar a função com o valor. Tentei também colocar o valor do calculo numa variável, e também aparece um erro dizendo que não é possivel comparar um valor Floadinput com Float. Então alguma solução para isto?

3º Como eu faço para ali no form de "Sexo" Colocar opções para invés da pessoa digitar?

OBS: Ali no views.py percebam que há respform e cadform, a dúvida Nº 1, é em respeito a isso, tem como eu fazer em só 1? Tipo, em cadform eu realizar o respform tbm?

Obrigado, desde já!

Models:

```
class Responsavel(models.Model):
    nome_responsavel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telefone_responsavel = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    endereco_responsavel = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_responsavel


class Aluno(models.Model):
    nome_aluno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    idade_aluno = models.DateField()
    peso_aluno = models.FloatField()
    altura_aluno = models.FloatField()

    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    aluno_responsavel = models.ForeignKey(Responsavel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_aluno
```

Views:

```
class cadform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Aluno
        fields = ['nome_aluno', 'idade_aluno', 'peso_aluno', 'altura_aluno', 'sexo']

    class respform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Responsavel
        fields = ['nome_responsavel', 'telefone_responsavel', 'endereco_responsavel']

    def cadastrar_aluno(request, template_name='contas/cadform.html'):
    resp = respform(request.POST or None)
    form = cadform(request.POST or None)
    if resp.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        resp.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'resp': resp} )
```

HTML De Cadastro

```
   {% extends 'contas/base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Cadastro de Aluno
{% endblock title %}


{% block nav %}
Cadastrar Aluno
{% endblock  %}


{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ resp.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Cadastrar
    </button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

O atributo de base de dados "sexo" é, tal como outras, uma tabela de SCD (Slowly Changing Dimension), não terá grandes alterações ao longo do tempo, logo, podes passar a utilizar CHOICES em Django. Depois as opções serão renderizadas pelo Django UI engine no {{ form.as_p }} e apresenta uma dropdownlist com as opções.

```
class Aluno(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'Female',),
        ('M', 'Male',),
        ('U', 'Unsure',),
    )
    nome_aluno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    idade_aluno = models.DateField()
    peso_aluno = models.FloatField()
    altura_aluno = models.FloatField()

    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=SEX_CHOICES)
    aluno_responsavel = models.ForeignKey(Responsavel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_aluno
```

Comment: Oi, ele fica assim quando eu adiciono o choice: 
https://imgur.com/a/ykGwcNd

Comment: Olá viva, esqueci que estás a utilizar o teu próprio custom template, se ativares o admin option em Django basta isso, para o teu caso falta view importar as choices do models, algo assim from .models import SEX_CHOICES, e na view cadForm sexo = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=SEX_CHOICES), neste exemplo com radioselect ou  sexo= forms.CharField(label='Select sex', widget=forms.Select(choices=SEX_CHOICES)).

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (sexo) specified for Aluno
deu esse erro aqui, brother :(

Answer (score 0):

verifica se colocaste assim:

Já testei, olha imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
class cadform(ModelForm):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'Female',),
        ('M', 'Male',),
        ('U', 'Unsure',),
    )
    sexo= forms.CharField(label='Select sex', widget=forms.Select(choices=SEX_CHOICES))
    class Meta:
        model = Aluno
        fields = ['nome_aluno', 'idade_aluno', 'peso_aluno', 'altura_aluno', 'sexo']


class respform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Responsavel
        fields = ['nome_responsavel', 'telefone_responsavel', 'endereco_responsavel']

    def cadastrar_aluno(request, template_name='app/cadform.html'):
        resp = respform(request.POST or None)
        form = cadform(request.POST or None)
        if resp.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            resp.save()
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'resp': resp} )
```

Comment: Oi, copiei e colei seu codigo: https://imgur.com/a/HHgk3qk

Comment: Acabei parando, por desanimar em não conseguir fazer isto.

Comment: Olá viva, não desanimes. A curva de aprendizagem de uma framework é sempre elevada, mas depois vais ver que vais ter uma produtividade elevada.

Comment: Quanto ao teu código, como antes não tinhas partilhado na imagem o que estavas a utilizar, não sabia como estavas a fazer GET do form, é o que te falta aí. Vou colocar o código da forms.py.

Answer (score 0):

A linha que adicionei à urls.py, mais o forms.py, com a classe AlunoView é que o django consegue carregar com o pedido GET a form para a view:

urls

```
 url(r'^cadastra', app.forms.AlunoView.as_view(), name='my-view'),
```

forms

```
"""
Definition of forms.
"""

from django import forms
from django.views import View
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .models import Aluno, Responsavel

class cadform(ModelForm):
    SEX_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'Female',),
        ('M', 'Male',),
        ('U', 'Unsure',),
    )
    sexo= forms.CharField(label='Select sex', widget=forms.Select(choices=SEX_CHOICES))
    class Meta:
        model = Aluno
        fields = ['nome_aluno', 'idade_aluno', 'peso_aluno', 'altura_aluno', 'sexo']


class respform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Responsavel
        fields = ['nome_responsavel', 'telefone_responsavel', 'endereco_responsavel']

    def cadastrar_aluno(request, template_name='contas/cadform.html'):
        resp = respform(request.POST or None)
        form = cadform(request.POST or None)
        if resp.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            resp.save()
            return redirect('index')
        return render(request, template_name, {'form': form, 'resp': resp} )

class AlunoView(View):

    form_class = cadform
    template_name = 'contas/cadform.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```